# Web Workers in Angular

Tags: angular, web-worker, angular-cli-v6

I'm trying to figure out why when I run `npx ng generate web-worker app`, I'm getting this error: `Schematic "web-worker" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".`

my angular cli is: `6.2.7`
angular-core is: `6.1.7`

what version of angular started allowing developers to `generate web-worker`?
is this not a good use case for npx?
I also tried using `ng` from my node_modules and got the same error.

let me know if I need to post more info.

Alternatively I would like to know how to implement web-workers for my angular app; `ng generate` seemed like a streamlined way to do so, but I'm open to other options if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular cli support for web worker starts from Angular 8.
To upgrade you angular version for project you can follow these steps-
1.  npm install -g @angular/cli 
2.  ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

The cli support for web workers comes in Angular 8. You need to update your angular version.